# Problem when clicking "Add to cart" in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, e-commerce

I'm trying to build my second React project which is an ecommerce website, but I'm facing some problems.
When I do click on "add to cart" of any item, this item it doesn't want to get added, but when i click again "add to cart" for the same item, it get added and the amount equal to 2. so the first click doesn't show it was added but somehow it stores the amount.

Thank you for advance.

**App.jsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./pages/home/Principal"
import Shop from "./pages/shop/Shop"
import Contact from "./pages/contact/Contact"
import About from "./pages/about/About"
import NotFound from "./pages/notFound/NotFound"
import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout"
import Privacy from "./pages/privacy/Privacy"
import Returns from "./pages/returns/Returns"
import ShopLayout from "./components/shopLayout/ShopLayout"
import ProductDetails from "./pages/productDetails/ProductDetails"
import Cart from "./pages/cart/Cart"
import useFetch from './hooks/useFetch';


function App() {

  const {products} = useFetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/`)

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
          <Route element={<ShopLayout />}>
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Shop products={products}/>} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<Privacy />} />
          <Route path="/shipping-returns" element={<Returns />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Shop.jsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ProductItem from '../../components/productItem/ProductItem';
import './shop.css';

function Shop({products}) {

    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

    function addToCart(item) {
        let productItem = cartItems.find(product => product.id === item.id)
       
        if(productItem) {
            productItem.amount += 1;
            //setCartItems([...cartItems])
            setCartItems([...cartItems])
            console.log("Your item has been updated")
            console.log(cartItems)
        } else {
            item.amount = 1;
            setCartItems([item, ...cartItems])
            console.log("Your item has been added")
            console.log(cartItems)
        }
        
    }

    return (
        <div className='shop'>
            Shop
            <div className='product-list container'>
            {
                products?.map(product => <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} addToCart={addToCart}/>)
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shop
```

**ProductItem.jsx**

```
import './productItem.css'
import { FaShoppingCart } from "react-icons/fa";

function ProductItem({product, addToCart}) {
    
    return (
        <div className='product-item'>
            <div className="product-item__image">
                <img className="product-item__img" src={product?.image} alt="image of the product" />
            </div>
            <div className="product-item__price">
                <span className="product-item__new-price">${Math.round(product?.price * (1 - product?.promotion/100))}</span>
                <span className="product-item__old-price">${product?.price}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="product-item__title">{product?.title}</div>
            <button className="btn product-item__btn" onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to cart <FaShoppingCart /></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductItem
```

Comment: try setCartItems((prev) => [...prev]) and setCartItems((prev) => [item, ...prev])

Comment: @TomFan I tried it but still it gives the same result. Thank you anyway